# TextView.setText() crashes app

Tags: android

I've got a textView (called tvCurrentBeat) and whenever I try use setText(), my app crashes on start up. If I remove this line of code, the app works as it should.

XML Code:

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvCurrentBeat"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivDividerMiddle"
      android:layout_below="@+id/ivDividerMiddle"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:text="Current Beat:"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Variable Initialization:

```
tvCurrentBeat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCurrentBeat);
```

Other code:

```
new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run();

            while (true) {
                if (metronomeOn) {
                    metronome = new Metronome(10000);
                    metronome.play();
                    metronomeOn = false;
                }
                tvCurrentBeat.setText("Current Beat: ");
            }
        }

    }.start();
```

This is all the code that affects this textview. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update UI elements from a background thread. You need to create a Runnable and update them via that. Although there are other options for doing this, this is the one I tend to use most often.

Here is an example:

```
private Handler threadHandler = new Handler();

// ...

while (true) {
    if (metronomeOn) {
        metronome = new Metronome(10000);
        metronome.play();
        metronomeOn = false;
    }
    threadHandler.post(updateRunnable);
}

// ...

final Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        tvCurrentBeat.setText("Current Beat: ");
    }
};
```

An alternative is to use `runOnUiThread()` which just runs your stuff on the main thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();

        while (true) {
            if (metronomeOn) {
                metronome = new Metronome(10000);
                metronome.play();
                metronomeOn = false;
            }
            tvCurrentBeat.setText("Current Beat: ");
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: Even though this no longer made the app crash (Thank you for that), it's makes the UI really really non responsive, it takes 3-5 seconds for a button click to respond now. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @user2522128 Hm, odd. On your original code, try swap out your first line for: `runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){` and see if there's a change.

Comment: I actually got rid of the handler and just used a runOnUiThread and now it works as it should! Thanks a lot

Comment: I went with option number one and it worked like a charm. THANK YOU!!!!!!!! I can't believe this is option number three on a google search for this crash.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to update the `UI` on a background `Thread`. That's a no no. You need to either use [runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Something like

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
           tvCurrentBeat.setText("Current Beat: ");
        }
    });
}
```

You may also want to read [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

Answer (score 2):

> This is all the code that affects this textview. Any ideas?

In Android there is restriction that tells you that you can manipulate with UI element(s) only from their origin Thread (as @Delyan pointed out in comments).

You created worker (background) Thread that is not synchronized with Main (UI) Thread and doesn't allow UI updates (for security and smooth-running reasons)

You have a few choices how to achieve your goal:

- A usage of runOnUiThread()
- Handler
- AsyncTask

All mentioned structures are synchronized or provides methods which are synchronized with UI Thread and allow manipulating with UI.

Comment: Actually the restriction has recently gotten a bit stronger - it's now the main thread, not just the origin. Most notably, WebView throws a warning if you instantiate it on a different thread (even if it's not attached to a view hierarchy).

Comment: @Delyan good to know man, i should look at it, interesting. Recently released Android 4.3 also fixed some "good" bugs in system for example manipulating with GPS from Java code...